# Representing relative addressing in byte code using Java

Tags: java, hex

I'm trying to represent relative addressing mode in Java. As we know, with relative addressing the operand must take a value between -128 and +127, as relative addressing uses 2's complement to represent whether the operand should be added or subtracted from the base value.

However I'm struggling to convert this into its hexadecimal representation.

2's complement form uses the most significant bit to determine whether the bit pattern in question is positive or negative, hence the reason for the range of -128 to +127.

Let's say we have the relative address operand `*+3A`, which states that the user wants to add `3A` to the value held in the program counter. This is simple enough as `3A` converts to `00111010` binary.

But then how do I go about representing `*-3A` in Java? If I convert 3A to decimal, which is `58` and then negate it to get `-58` and then convert that back to hexadecimal, will that work?

I'm not sure if this is just something that's really simple and I'm making it into something bigger than it actually is.

Comment: *YOU* are defining your syntax. If you want `*-3A` to mean 58 bytes before, then that's what it means. As a single-byte signed offset value, it would of course be *stored* as the byte value `0xC6`, i.e. `-58` *(decimal)*.

Comment: Answer yes it will, and yes you are.  The number is fundamentally a signed number between -128 and +127.  If you choose to display it in hex or allow the user to enter it in hex, that is fine.  Represent it internally as a `byte`, and just don't forget to do proper bounds checking when you convert from the user syntax to internal representation; e.g. don't allow a branch of `8E` *backwards* ...

Comment: To be honest using unsigned hex as the user-visible syntax for a relative address is a bad idea for end-user understanding.  It would make more sense (to me and and the typical user) to use signed decimal.

Answer (score 0):

We have a couple things going on.

Two's Complement is the representation for negative integers in all modern machines. To negate an integer, you:

- take the bitwise complement, and then
- add one, ignoring the carry-bit.

So this needs to be done in the context of a specific word-size. If your allowable range is -128 to 127, you are dealing with an 8-bit "word".

The second issue is how you encode the result for human (or compiler) consumption. In either case, simply using a signed decimal integer is probably ideal.